# Why is from code import * different from entering that very same code directly into the REPL?

Tags: python

...indeed, entering

```
a = 0
def func(): global a; a = 1

func()
print(a)
```

directly within the REPL gives **1**.

While (after resetting the console) entering

```
from code import *

func()
print(a)
```

gives **0**. Why?

*code.py* is

```
a = 0
def func(): global a; a = 1
```

Comment: in one case you *call* `func()`. that sets `a` to `1`. if you just *import* you do not call the function yet (i.e. the body of the function is not executed).

Comment: Import does not mean calling the function inside it.

Comment: If you mean *after* calling the function, that happens for the same reason that if you e.g. assign the value of a dictionary to another variable `x = d[y]` then mutate the dictionary `d[y] += 1` the variable `x` doesn't seem to change. `import *` binds each *value* from the module to a separate name in your namespace. Try `import code` then referring to `code.a` and `code.func` instead.